# Using DateDiff to Calculate the Difference in Days

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

In the expression below, I am trying to calculate the difference in days between the Created date and today's date. If it is less than 30 days then output "1", otherwise output "0"

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d",(Format(CDate(Fields!Created.Value), "MM/dd/yyyy")), (Format(CDate(Today()), "MM/dd/yyyy")))<30, "1", "0")
```

Both values in "Created" and Today() are formatted with the date and time so I use Format and CDate to extract just the date. When I run the report, it displays all "0" and I know that is incorrect. Is there something wrong with the expression?

Comment: Expression looks fine. Change 30 to 3000 and see if you still get 0s or does it now show 1s?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a number of things wrong with that expression: You take dates, explicitly convert them to dates, then using format convert them to strings then implicitly convert them back to dates to do your date comparison. That's a lot of heavy lifting for no benefit. You are also using SQL syntax in a VBA expression. Your result is also a string when it probably should be an integer.

Your expression should look more like this:

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Created.Value, Today) < 30, 1, 0)
```